# Замена текста во время вовода. iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

Здравствуй %username%

Помоги решить задачу.

Есть UITextField в который вводится определенная последовательность цифр

Суть в том, что я хочу, что бы во время ввода, каждые 4 символа, пробел подставлялся автоматически
При помощи каких методов или классов это реализуется?

У Андройда я использовал TextWatcher. Какой аналог у iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом делегата UITextField:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Comment: (NSRange)range Это текущая позиция курсора?
replacementString:(NSString *)string А это вся строка целиком?

Answer (score 1):

Более детально описано тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083605/formatting-a-uitextfield-for-credit-card-input-like-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx